# Java different reference type and class object

Tags: java, inheritance

If `A abc = new B()` and `A` , `B` classes are having inheritance relationship, what is the advantage of using reference type `A` instead of `B`, what if `B` was used? Also what methods can now `B`'s object access(all `A` and `B` methods or something else)? Also if A and B both have same methods, B overrides it, but if they've different methods, object can access whose methods here?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have:

```
public class A {

    public void a(){

    }
}

public class B extends A{

    public void b(){

    }
}
```

You can NOT use `B b = new A();`

You can use `A a = new A();` Here you have access to `a()` method.

You can use `A a = new B();` Here you have access to `a()` method.

You can use `B b = new B();` Here you have access to both `a(), b()` methods.

So what is the advantage of having `A a = new B()`?

Suppose you have classes B, C, D, E and all of them extend the class A or implement the interface A. Now you can have `A a = new B(); A a = new C(); A a = new D()` and check the type at runtime then cast the object to specific class type so you do NOT need to declare 3 variable for each type. You have one container(variable) for all A type variable and it's child (B, C, D) too.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take Java Collections API as an example. For sake of brevity, consider the following hierarchy:

```
Collection -> ArrayList
```

- [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) has a method [`Collection::isEmpty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#isEmpty--)
- [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has a method [`ArrayList::add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-)

Now, these statements are valid:

- An instance of `Collection` can use the method `isEmpty()`.
- An instance of `ArrayList`can use methods `isEmpty()` and `add()`.

Now it depends what do you want to do with the instance. If you need to add new elements, use the implementation which allows it. If not, it's a good practice to use the minimal implementation or object you really need.

Example: If you need a size of the returned List from DAO, use the `Collection` instead of `List` or any of its implementations:

```
Collection collection = dao.getListFromDatabase();
int size = collection.size();
```